# Make the Google Chart lines occupy the entire area chart

Tags: google-visualization

I use Google line chart for my project, but, I want that lines start from border, and remove that space between lines start and end.

[image: Google Line Charts I have]

But I want this:

[image: Google Line Chart I wants]

Is this possible? thanks x ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the x-axis (first column in the data table),

use numbers --> `2004`

instead of strings --> `'2004'`

Comment: It works, but what if my x-axis (first col) is a date? If I changed to numbers it show number with thousands separator 2004 -> 2,004

Comment: a date will work the same as numbers, these create what is known as a _continuous_ axis. strings produce a _discrete_ axis...

Comment: as for number format, you could use --> `hAxis: {format: '0000'}`

Comment: Got it, thank you, I have see all the info for format data on Google site API, fixed, thanks a lot, see you guys, be careful.